# Is there a tool that searches for a specific BTC amount in a specific date range?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Suppose I want to search for a transaction of [exactly 445 BTC](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1j7y2y/yesterday_i_represented_a_client_who_paid_445/) in the date range 27 July 2013 and Aug 3rd 2013 ... is there an (online?) tool that has this kind of search capabilities?

Comment: People who downvote: Please add a comment explaning why you don't like the question (if it is not super obvious, which in this case I don't think that it is). It's hard to improve if you don't know what to improve.

Comment: you posted on reddit that its tracable but linked here where you ask *how* to trace it? which shows that you dont *know* how to trace it... so it might not really be tracable right?

Comment: @BitcoinFan we know it's traceable, as it's in the blockchain. It's just a matter of whether there's a tool readily available to find it or not, which is a different issue.

Comment: The date doesn't line up, but is [this transaction](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/eae5f8cff22ffa45ddaeb255113f49ad93a90d0464e4e1d44e346aca4471ca94) what you're looking for? I don't know much about Bitcoin, but can transactions be dated in the future, e.g. August 3rd, 2013?

Comment: It may be possible to locate the exact Block chain transaction or multiple transactions if multiple addresses were used. But still, how would you associate the block chain transaction to the actual person's identity? If it was transferred out of MtGox or CoinBase, you would probably need a court order to get the name. But if it was transferred out of a private wallet, then there is no way of knowing who it came from.

Comment: @JohnBensin I think it's not the one, wrong date. But in any case, the question is indeed about finding/building a tool to search for such transactions, not about a specific tx.

Comment: Heh, people were expecting an answer, and were surprised to find none. In any case, it's obviously easy to build a tool (search engine) that searches for transactions in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

[Blockchair](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin) allow you to query the bitcoin blockchain with lots of parameter such as date, BTC output amount, fee amount etc...

Here is your request:
https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?q=time(2013-07-27..2013-08-03),output_total(44500000000)#

Unfortunately it bring no result but you can change the parameters

Comment: Here is the request to search for the Bitcoin Pizza Day transaction https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?q=time(2010-05-22),output_total(1000000000000)